# Group translations in .arb files

Tags: flutter, flutter-localizations

Is there a way to group translations like this in .ARB files in intl / flutter localizations ? I used the 'intl' extension but when I tried this method, it gave me an error. Is there another syntax do the same idea? Even using another package like easy_localization?
[image]